# How can I avoid splitting on a comma in brackets?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string below which I want to split in String array with multiple delimiters.

The delimiters are comma (`,`), semicolon (`;`), "OR" and "AND".
But I do not want to split on a comma if it's in brackets.

Example input:

```
device_name==device503,device_type!=GATEWAY;site_name<site3434 OR country==India AND location==BLR; new_name=in=(Rajesh,Suresh)
```

I am able to split the String with regex, but it doesn't handle commas in brackets correctly.

How can I fix this?

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("(,|;|OR|AND)");
String[] parts = ptn.split(query);
for(String p:parts){
   System.out.println(p);
   queryParams.add(p.trim());
}
```

Comment: Input is : country==India, location==BLR; new_name=in=(Rajesh, Suresh) and Output is in list with elements : country==India , location==BLR, new_name=in=(Rajesh, Suresh)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative look-ahead:.

```
String[] parts = input.split(",(?![^()]*\\))|;| OR | AND ")
```

Or an uglier (but perhaps conceptually simpler) way you could do it would be to replace any commas within brackets with a temporary placeholder, then do the split and replace the placeholders with real commas in the results.

```
String input = "X,Y=((A,B),C) OR Z";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group().replaceAll(",", "_COMMA_"));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);

String[] parts = sb.toString().split("(,|;| OR | AND )");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part.replace("_COMMA_", ","));
}
```

Prints:

```
X
Y=((A,B),C)
Z
```

Alternatively, you could write your own little tokenizer that reads the input character-by-character using `charAt(index)` or define a grammar for an off-the-shelf parser.

Comment: Thanks @aetheria its working for me . Regex is better and simple .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**negative look-ahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (?!...), which looks at the following characters, and if those characters match the pattern in brackets, the overall match will fail.

```
String query = "device_name==device503,device_type!=GATEWAY;site_name<site3434 OR country==India AND location==BLR; new_name=in=(Rajesh,Suresh)";
String[] parts = query.split("\\s*(,(?![^()]*\\))|;|OR|AND)\\s*");
for(String part: parts)
   System.out.println(part);
```

Output:

```
device_name==device503
device_type!=GATEWAY
site_name<site3434
country==India
location==BLR
new_name=in=(Rajesh,Suresh)
```

So in this case we check whether the characters following the `,` are 0 or more characters which aren't either `(` or `)`, followed by a `)`, and if this is true, the `,` match fails.

This won't work if you can have nested brackets.

---

Note:

- `String` also has a `split` method (as used above), which is useful for simplicity's sake (but would be slower than reusing the same `Pattern` over and over again for multiple `String`s).
- You can add `\\s*` (0 or more whitespace characters) to your regex to remove any spaces before or after a delimiter.
- If you're using `|` without anything before or after (e.g. `"a|b|c"`), you don't need to put it in brackets.